# Move ImageView smooth

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, imageview

I am moving object in x and y ways with different speed. I'm doing this with timer, which every interval (0.01) calls function which move object like that (example):

```
 image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x-1, image.center.y-2);
```

Everything works just fine. But it's not so smooth as I suspected that it will be. Is there some other way to move ImageView smoother? I heard that timers are not the best to use. Is there a way to do it with current time?

Comment: Do you not get error when you run this line?  image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x-1, image.center.-2); as y isn't set..

Comment: Sorry my mistake when writting this.

Comment: @user3215624, do not forget to accept (upvote) answer (answers) that were useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to use `Animation` blocks

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x-1, image.center.y-2);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];
                 }];
```

Comment: One more question. This is animation happens just once. If i put this in some loop like while, it just stops my app? And of course it would bi silly to put this animation into timer, because i would get the same result i had before. So how to make it to least till (example) a=!true ?

Comment: And sorry I can't up vote yet. My reputation is too low.

Comment: You can increase the duration time.

Comment: Sorry but just don't get it :) The animation still happens just once. It not affect on duration time I set. I want that my image moves each 0.01 second for 1 pixel. Sorry if I am making silly questions, but just don't understand this animation.

Comment: So you want to animate infinite times?

Comment: So just make that function recursive

Comment: Tried before. CPU is up to 99% in that case.

Comment: Try to use `animationRepeatCount` of UIView to -1 in completion block

Comment: Edited answer. Pls check

Comment: Tried with -1 and HUGE_VALF but not working? It stays still. And also if I put any number there won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use animation for this. For example `UIView` s method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

NSTimer not fires exactly at the moment you expect to. System can move it a little forward or backward. Also native animation uses subpixel smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
   //set final center
}];
```

Or change interval to ~0.0416.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
CGPoint endCenter = CGPointMake(x, y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                         animations:^{
                             image.center = endCenter;
                         }];
```

Also if you want to move it to some starting point x,y you can do it like this:

```
CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                         animations:^{
                             image.frame = endFrame;
                         }];
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) to have more control of the animation.